# Error al pasar un array multidimensional como parámetro de una función en google apps script

Tags: javascript, json, array, google-apps-script

Estoy intentando pasar un array de 2 dimensiones como parámetro a una función, pero según el depurador cuando llega a la función tiene 3 dimensiones.

```
function Actualizar()
{
 var ResponseKryptono = 
 UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://engine2.kryptono.exchange/api/v1/dp?symbol=DGX_ETH");
 var json = JSON.parse(ResponseKryptono.getContentText());
 Consolidar (json.asks, 15)
}
```

En la siguiente imagen del depurador se ve como **json.asks** tiene 2 dimensiones

[image: En esta imagen se ve como json.asks tiene 2 dimensiones]

```
function Consolidar(Book, Limite)
{
  var Acum = 0
  for (i=0 ; i<Book.length ; i++){
     Acum= Acum + Book[i][2]
     if (Acum>=Limite) { 
       var j = i
       i=Book.length
     }       
  }  
  return Acum
}
```

Ahora el parámetro **Book** (cuyo origen es json.asks) parece tener 2 dimensiones pero está referenciado con 3 dimensiones ¿¿¿¿????

[image: Ahora el parámetro Book parece tener 3 dimensiones ¿¿¿¿????]

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta

Answer (score 0):

La herramienta de depuración de código tiene un "bug" conocido que provoca el comportamiento descrito así que no te confíes en este, en su lugar, usa técnicas y/o herramientas más robustas, pero en especial estudia cómo funcionan los arrays y objetos en JavaScript y Google Apps Script.

Referencias

- [AS debugging issue: array element count increases ironically](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36765017)